# How to delete a google sheet after a certain time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small project that read from a master Data sheet. Once the user put his number in search sheet. a new sheet with that number created. I want that sheet to be deleted after a certain time i.e 5 minutes. BTW, another user sheet might be created any time so i want the code delete each user's sheet accordingly.

There might be another solution to delete all created sheets except first two sheets (Data sheet and search sheet)

Could someone help on that code plz.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{      

    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Search');
    var val = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
    sheet.copyTo(source).setName(val);


  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Search') 
  {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A2') 
    {

      SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName('Search')
      .getRange('B2')
      .setValue('=QUERY(Data!A2:M,"Select * WHERE H ="""&A2&"""")')
                  
                  Utilities.sleep(10000);
                  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
                  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(val);
                  //sheet2.activate();
                      ss.deleteSheet(sheet2);
                        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Once the user put his number in search sheet. a new sheet with that number created`. How is this being created? That doesn't show up on your script, at least. Also, what's the reason for using `sleep`?

Comment: line of code below is to copy search result sheet as new sheet named as user's number  sheet.copyTo(source).setName(val); sleep is to wait before deleting user's sheet.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I failed to see that line yesterday. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime after you create the new sheet, you can [create a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)) to delete it after 5 minutes.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // ...
  var userSheet = sheet.copyTo(source).setName(val);
  // ...
  createDeletionTrigger_(userSheet);
  // ...
}

/**
 * Create a trigger to delete the specified sheet after a set amount of time.
 * @param {Sheet} sheet - The sheet to be deleted.
 */
function createDeletionTrigger_(sheet) {
  DeletionQueue.append(sheet.getSheetId());
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('deleteNextUserSheet').timeBased().after(5 * 1000).create();
}

/**
 * Delete the next sheet in the user's queue and the delete the calling trigger.
 */
function deleteNextUserSheet(e) {
  DeletionQueue.deleteNext();
  deleteTrigger(e.triggerUid);
}

/**
 * Find a trigger by its unique ID and delete it.
 * @param {string} triggerUid - The trigger's unique ID.
 */
function deleteTrigger(triggerUid) {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    var trigger = triggers[i];
    if (trigger.getUniqueId() === triggerUid) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
      break;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * The queue of IDs for sheets that should be deleted. 
 */
var DeletionQueue = {
  key: 'deletionQueue',
  cache: CacheService.getUserCache(),
  
  /**
   * Get the queue of sheet IDs in the order they were added.
   * @returns {number[]}
   */
  get: function() {
    var queue = this.cache.get(this.key);
    return queue == null ? [] : JSON.parse(queue);
  },
  
  /**
   * Append a new sheet ID to the queue for future deletion.
   * @param {number} sheetId - The new sheet ID to append.
   */
  append: function(sheetId) {
    var queue = this.get();
    queue.push(sheetId);
    this.update(queue);
  },
  
  /**
   * Replace the cached queue with a new array of sheet IDs.
   * @param {number[]} queue - The new array of sheet IDs.
   */
  update: function(sheetIds) {
    this.cache.put(this.key, JSON.stringify(sheetIds));
  },
  
  /**
   * Delete the next sheet (FIFO) and update the cached queue.
   */
  deleteNext: function() {
    var queue = this.get();
    var sheetId = queue.shift();
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
    for (var i in sheets) {
      var sheet = sheets[i];
      if (sheet.getSheetId() === sheetId) {
        spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
        this.update(queue);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can't pass a value into a trigger, so you need to save the sheet somewhere. I'm using the [Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache) to save the sheet IDs as IDs cannot change, but sheet names can. (Note that the cache defaults to a 10-minute expiration, so you'd need to adjust the code if you want sheet IDs persisted longer than that.) Specifically, I'm using the [User Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service#getUserCache()), so different users won't delete each other's sheets.

Because this is a queue, the same user *should* be able to create multiple sheets and they *should* be correctly deleted in the order they were created.

There is a [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) of 20 triggers/user/script and, maddeningly, it does apply to "disabled" triggers. So you'll want to delete the trigger after it's used, which can be accomplished using the `triggerUid` passed by its [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events).

Comment: Is it necessary to delete executed triggers or leave them?!

Comment: @Andous Yes! Good catch  I updated the code to delete the trigger after use.